# The number of four digit numbers that can be formed from digits 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 if each number contains digit 1 is

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

What is the number of four digit numbers that can be formed from the digits $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7$ so that each number contains digit $1$?

The answer is $750$ but I am not able to find it.

Comment: Please complete your sentence, you seem to have cut off there...

Comment: Are the digits necessarily different?

Comment: Yes , u cannot use one digit more than once

Comment: There are 4 choices for where the $1$ is located, and of the 3 other digits, the leftmost has 7 choices, the 2nd leftmost has 6 remaining choices, and the rightmost has 5 remaining choices.

Comment: I've written an implementation in js just for [fun](http://tpcg.io/_IM1MG6). The answer is 750.

Answer (score 2):

Since we are looking for $4$-digit numbers, the first (thousands) digit can't be $0$.

Let's split cases:

### Case 1: first digit is $1$.

In this case, we pick $3$ digits in order out of the remaining $7$, there are $7\cdot6\cdot5=210$ possibilities.

### Case 2: first digit is not $1$.

There are $6$ ways to choose the first digit ($2,3,...,7$), $3$ ways to place the digit $1$ (hundreds, tens, ones), and $6\cdot5$ (pick $2$ in order from the remaining $6$ digits) ways to choose the other digits. So there are $6\cdot3\cdot6\cdot5=540$ possibilities in this case.

### Total

In total, there are $210+540=750$ possibilities to choose the number.

Comment: The answer is 480, I already mentioned that in question.

Comment: @user163054 If it's so, how do you know?

Comment: I only have the answer, not complete solution

Comment: @user163054 Unless there are additional conditions that you did not mention, the correct answer is $750$.

Comment: There isn't anything additional. And this question appeared in a test and many students got the answer.

Comment: I will ask them and confirm if there's really any mistake

Comment: No, I am a student.

Comment: @user163054 If you're asking them, you can ask, what steps they use.

Comment: OK , I will do ask them.

Comment: That the answer is obviously wrong doesn't need any asking. Even if we take it that $1$  doesn't appear at all in the four digit number, it evaluates to $6\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4 = 720$

Comment: @trueblueanil But if we know their steps, we can at least do something to correct them.

Comment: Sorry for so much CONFUSION!!!.YOUR ANSWER IS CORRECT. There was really mistake. So the correct answer is (750)